# Programmatically close an RMA?

Tags: php, magento-enterprise, magento-1.14, rma

I've been poking around the RMA class file to try and find a way to close it, and it would seem that simply running `$rma->close();` should be enough, but that fails without displaying an error.

Has anyone found another way to close an RMA through PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple mistake, seeing as there was no example code I could follow and I was just going off what I read in the class file, I failed to realize that you needed to run `->save()` after closing the RMA.

The final line looks like this:

```
$rma->close()->save();
```